# Java Swing: How do I define one minimal dimension (of the two) for components?

Tags: java, swing, size, dimensions, layout-manager

To define minimal size successfully, I have to do the following:

```
// setting minimal width AND height
Dimension min = new Dimension(100, 100);
comp.setMinimumSize(min);
comp.setPreferredSize(min);
comp.setSize(min);
```

When I left one line out it doesn't work, which is strange, but it's not the point.

What do I do to limit **just one** of two dimensions (width **or** height) and let the component and/or the layout manager decide automatically about the **unspecified** dimension?

When I use a very small value for that dimension which I don't want to limit, many components are displayed wrong (i.e. too small).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default (i.e. if `setMinimumSize` has not been called on the component) `getMinimumSize` delegates to the component's layout manager, so you can try to redefine the `getMinimumSize` method as follows:

```
public Dimension getMinimumSize()
{
    return new Dimension(minWidth, super.getMinimumSize().height);
}
```

If you do this, remember that you should not call `setMinimumSize` on the component.

Comment: I don't understand: you mean I should override `getMinimumSize` of the component, or do you mean the layout manager? Thanks!

Comment: Override the method in the component. It will delegate to the layout manager as long as `setMinimumSize` has not been called on the component. By overriding the way I described you get "default behavior" for height, but you can specify a minimum width explicitly.

Comment: As a Java beginer, it first looked a complicated answer since I didn't want to write a new class to override its method. Then I leant it's possible to achive it like this: ```JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getMinimumSize()
            {
                return new Dimension(minWidth, super.getMinimumSize().height);
            }
        };```

Answer (score 0):

I propose an approach by myself:

For layout managers which align everything one axis (such as `BoxLayout`), one can specify "undefined dimension" set to `Integer.MAX`. It is strange, but it works. It seems that the axis which is opposite to the alignment axis is ignored (unless it's too small, as mentioned in the question).

```
private final static int UNSPECIFIED_DIMENSION = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

public static void setMinimalDimension(Component comp, int width, int height) {
  Dimension dim = new Dimension(width, height);
  comp.setMinimumSize(dim);
  comp.setPreferredSize(dim);
  comp.setSize(dim);
}

public static void setMinimalWidth(Component comp, int width) {
  setMinimalDimension(comp, width, UNSPECIFIED_DIMENSION);
}

public static void setMinimalHeight(Component comp, int height) {
  setMinimalDimension(comp, UNSPECIFIED_DIMENSION, height);
}
```

Works, as mentioned, with axis-aligning layout managers.

*Yes, there goes another mystery of Java Swing...*